# Filter EWS mailbox by recipient address using exchangelib

Tags: python, email, exchangewebservices, exchangelib

I'm writing a monitoring solution using **python3** with **exchangelib** and trying to count messages in our team's mailbox. One of the criteria: **recipient list must contain specific email address**.

When i use `filter()` with `author` or `subject` arguments script is working fine and return correct results.

But when i tried to filter by `to_recipients` or `to_recipients__contains` (which is list-type field), script throws an exception:

```
ValueError: EWS does not support filtering on field 'to_recipients'
```

Is there a way to filter mailbox by recipient `email_address`, avoiding to fetch all messages and than filtering it on the client side?

Answer (score 1):

[exchangelib maintainer here]

I don't think there is. You could try to flip the [is_searchable](https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib/blob/cc2e42717cfc1962b2969ec1259c9b20c5efd6f6/exchangelib/items.py#L534) flag on that field and search anyway, but I never could get filtering to work in my tests. I can't remember if it throws server errors, returns all items anyway, or returns an empty list.

I'm happy to accept patches it you do find a solution.